# combine two 16 bit integer to 32 bit float value c#

Tags: c#

I have to Combine two 16 bit integer and trying to convert into 32 bit float value in my service but I am not able to get. Finally I figure out how to do.

```
Int16 val1 = 0;
Int16 val2 = 16880;
```

output should be:

```
30
```

Comment: **Why** should the output be 30?

Comment: How about `(val1 + val2) / 562` ?

Comment: good answer but if you are getting continuous value from device or any IOT controller, this will help you for single value you want to do means you can go with you way :)

Comment: sorry this is totally unclear what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
Int16 val1 = 0;
Int16 val2 = 16880;

var byteval1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(val1);
var byteval2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(val2);

byte[] temp2 = new byte[4];
temp2[0] = byteval1[0];
temp2[1] = byteval1[1];
temp2[2] = byteval2[0];
temp2[3] = byteval2[1];

float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(temp2, 0);
```

Comment: Try `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct SingleConversion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int16 Int16A;
    
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public Int16 Int16B;
    
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Single Single;
}` instead, not as many memory locations to deal with.